Targetting a specific button in a list of frames in tkinter
I created a list of 9 frames in Tkinter, and each frame has a group of 9 buttons arranged as a grid:
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    window = tkinter.Tk()

    
    frame = []
    for i in range(9):
        f = tkinter.Frame(window, bg="red")
        frame.append(f)

        
        button = [[0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0]]
        for j in range(3):
            for k in range(3):
                button[j][k] = tkinter.Button(frame[i], text="yo", padx=2, pady=2, command=lambda x=i, y=j, z=k: change_value(x,y,z))
                button[j][k].grid(row=j,column=k)

So now, every frame[i] has 9 buttons ie button[j][k].
I am trying to target the text of a single button in a particular frame from the change_value() function. How do I capture this? frame[i].button[j][k]["text"] does not work. Is it possible to target a particular button in a frame?

command= needs function's name without () and without arguments. And when you press button then tkinter will use () to execute this function. If you want to assign function with arguments then you have to use lambda - and because you run it in for-loop then you have to assign values to new variables - like command=lambda x=i,y=j,z=k: change_value(x,y,z)

I went ahead and made that change and the interface renders now. However, I am still having trouble targeting the text of a button inside a specific frame.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

if you use command=lambda:change_value(i,jk) then for-loop will use the same value ini,j,k because it doesn't send value (from variables) to function but only reference to these variables - and at the same time for-loop will change value in these variables - so when you press button then function will get last value from for-loop.

So I used print() to print the values of x,y,z from the change_value() function. And everytime I press a button, it is actaully giving me the correct values of x,y,z ie the correct frame number and button number. I'm just having trouble on how to refer to the frame and button using x,y,z now

It is because you initialize button in every iteration of the outer for loop.  You need to change button to attribute of the frame as below:
frame = []
for i in range(9):
    f = tkinter.Frame(window, bg="red", padx=10, pady=10)
    f.pack()
    frame.append(f)

    # create attribute "button" in the frame
    f.button = [[0,0,0],
                [0,0,0],
                [0,0,0]]
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(3):
            # use f.button instead of button
            f.button[j][k] = tkinter.Button(frame[i], text="yo", padx=2, pady=2, command=lambda x=i, y=j, z=k: change_value(x,y,z))
            f.button[j][k].grid(row=j,column=k)

Then you can use frame[x].button[y][z] to access the required button.

This works!! So the button has to be added as an attribute

You can use this as a basic idea, If at all you have to use dynamic variables for the widgets, the easiest method is using the the dynamic variables as the keys of a dictionary. As and when we have to call any specific value of the dictionary, we all know how to call the value (i.e) dct[spefific key]
from tkinter import *

def change_value(x, y, z):
    #Some code to be executed

window = Tk()

#declare an empty dictionary for frames
frme_dct ={}

# declare a dictionary for buttons
btn_dct ={}

for i in range(9):

    
    #declare the frame's dynamiv variable as the key of theframe_dct. And Value being the respective frame-widget itself
    frme_dct[f'f_{i}'] = Frame(window, bg='red')
    frme_dct[f'f_{i}'].pack() #instead of 'pack', use whichever thr method you prefer
    
    
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(3):
                
            # Declare the dynamic variable btn as the keys of the btn_dct. And Value being the respective button itself
            btn_dct[f'btn{i}__{j}{k}'] = Button(frme_dct[f'f_{i}'],text="yo", padx=2, pady=2, command=lambda x=i, y=j, z=k: change_value(x,y,z))
                
            btn_dct[f'btn{i}__{j}{k}'].grid(row=j,column=k)
                
window.mainloop()

# With the above technique if you want to call specific button or widget, you can directly call like dct[key]
        
    
    

